# Get the Query for Line Numbers from the Sales Order Form in Oracle EBS

Tags: oracle, oracleapplications, oracle-ebs

From the Front-end Application, we can see the **line number** like 1.1 , 2.1, 2.1.1 like this.
I only have the value of the **line_id**s.
I would like to get the query for the line numbers in Sales order Form with the use of their `line_id` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t.LINE_NUMBER || '.' || t.shipment_number line_number 
from oe_order_lines_all t 
WHERE T.HEADER_ID = &header_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

The line number could actually include more than just the shipment. This should be complete (from the [ONT Order Headers and Lines](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/ont-order-headers-and-lines/) Blitz Report):

```
select
rtrim(oola.line_number||'.'||oola.shipment_number||'.'||oola.option_number||'.'||oola.component_number||'.'||oola.service_number,'.') line_number
from
oe_order_lines_all oola
where
oola.line_id=:line_id
```